# laravel savemany with pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to save many objects with pivot data?
I have a many-to-many polymorphic relation and would like to do the following:

```
$attribute->texts()->saveMany([$value1, $value2], ['article_id' => 1]);
```

I already can do

```
$attribute->texts()->save($value1, ['article_id' => 1]);
```

Is there a way to achieve this with laravels eloquent?
Laravel version: 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which exact Laravel version are you using, but there is already `saveMany` method in `BelongsToMany` relationship (I'm looking at 5.4.28 now):

```
public function saveMany($models, array $pivotAttributes = [])
{
    foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
        $this->save($model, (array) Arr::get($pivotAttributes, $key), false);
    }

    $this->touchIfTouching();

    return $models;
}
```

so something like this should work.

Comment: I am using laravel 5.5. As mentioned above I tried that already, but in results in an error: article_id doesn't have a default value.